# Sending cross platform emails with PHP, how to handle line breaks?

Tags: php, email, cross-platform, sendmail, eol

When creating a script to send emails using the PHP `mail()` function I'm coming across issues with new lines. PHP on Unix systems expect headers to be separated with a `LF` character, despite what [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) say, **sendmail** then replaces these with the correct `CRLF`. However on Windows the message and headers are sent as  provided. This was described in a [long running PHP bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15841).

So I need a method of detecting whether the system is running the Unix version of **sendmail** in order to use `LF` and use `CRLF` on Windows. I'm aware of `PHP_EOL` but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of handling this.

Currently I'm building my message, as specified by the docs, like so.

```
<?php
$to      = "example@website.com";
$subject = "Email Subject Here";
$message = "Hello this is a plaintext\n message with a line break.";
$headers = array(
  "From: webmaster@example.com",
  "Reply-To: webmaster@example.com",
  "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()
);

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, join("\r\n", $headers));
if ($success) {
    echo "Mail Sent\n";
} else {
    echo "Mail Failed\n";
}
```

On Unix systems this results in the following message being sent to **sendmail** (`\r` and `\n` have been replaced by textual representations):

```
To: example@website.comLF
Subject: Email Subject HereLF
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 501:mail.phpLF
From: webmaster@example.comCRLF
Reply-To: webmaster@example.comCRLF
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.1LF
LF
Hello this is a plaintextLF
message with a line break.LF
```

When this is passed to **sendmail** all `LF` are replaced with `CRLF` resulting in duplicate carriage returns. Some mail servers then replace this additional `CR` with `CRLF` resulting in an additional line break and all headers, in this case after `From:`, are now part of the message body.

<strike>PHP actually inserts the `X-PHP-Originating-Script` header with incorrect line ending, which is a side issue but still annoying.</strike> *– Actually a PHP 5.3 bug, now fixed.*

Any ideas on an ideal way of handling this cross platform?

Thanks,

Aron

Answer (score 1):

This was a rather transient defect in the early 5.3 releases [see this bug notice](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50907)

Upgrade your PHP

Comment: Ah thanks, have updated my question to reflect this. I'm still looking for a way of handling the differing line endings required by `mail()` on Unix and Windows